# NavigationController Back button cause “Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported”

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

This issue is only on iPhone.
I have a tableView that will show detail page when I tap on it.
When I tap on the cell quickly, then tap "Back" on the detail screen's navigation bar, the app crashes.
This happens infrequently (1 out of 10 uses or less).

Code:

```
class Coordinator {
   func rootViewController() -> UISplitViewController {
      let master = createMasterViewController()
      let detail = createDetailViewController()
      self.splitViewController = createSplitViewController(master, detail) 
      return self.splitViewController
   }
   ...
   func didSelectDetail() {
      let detail = createDetailViewController()
      self.splitViewController.showDetailViewController(detail, sender: nil)
   }
}
```

Exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' is pushing the same view controller instance () more than once which is not supported and is most likely an error in the application

Answer (score 0):

this may happens if controller released from memory. If You created it as `var splitViewController: UIViewController!` - try to write instead `var splitViewController: UIViewController?`, and check on nil in each call like

```
 guard let controller = self.splitViewController else {
      print("Controller does not exist") 
      return
}
```